# Проблема с инициализацией User Control в WPF с параметрами

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется очень простой User Control:

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ArgumentXProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ArgumentX", typeof(int), typeof(TestControl));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ArgumentYProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ArgumentY", typeof(int), typeof(TestControl));
    private int result;

    public TestControl() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        result = ArgumentX + ArgumentY;
    }

    public int ArgumentX {
        get => (int)GetValue(ArgumentXProperty);
        set => SetValue(ArgumentXProperty, value);
    }
    public int ArgumentY {
        get => (int)GetValue(ArgumentYProperty);
        set => SetValue(ArgumentYProperty, value);
    }
}
```

В конструкторе мне необходимо работать с данными, которые передаются таким образом (представим, что где-то в другом XAML мне необходимо добавить данный элемент):

```
<TestControl ArgumentX="5" ArgumentY="10"/>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в этом самом конструкторе свойства не инициализируются с помощью тех аргументов, которые я передал в XAML. И если оставить код таким, какой есть сейчас, то "result" будет равен 0, а не 15. Но, после "отработки" конструктора значения в свойствах соответствуют тем, что я передал при инициализации.

Comment: Сделайте result вычисляемым свойством или методом, а не храните значение.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующим способом:

```
Loaded += (sender, args) =>
{
     result = ArgumentX + ArgumentY;
};
```